# could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device

Tags: linux, debian, postgresql

The posgtres sudden stopped on the server and the logs shows the following error:

```
2015-08-18 02:29:22 IST ERROR:  could not extend file "base/197893/198337": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:22 IST HINT:  Check free disk space.
2015-08-18 02:29:22 IST STATEMENT:  UPDATE "data_shipmentpptlmapping" SET "pptl_id" = '2558', "time" = '2015-08-17 20:40:47.163837+00:00', "bag_seal_status" = 'close', "
shipment_id_id" = 728518 WHERE "data_shipmentpptlmapping"."id" = 557513 
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2015-08-18 02:29:25 IST LOG:  could not write temporary 2015-08-18 04:29:04 IST LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2015-08-18 03:35:25 IST
```

And here is the postgres details:

```
postgres=# SHOW data_directory;
        data_directory        
------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
(1 row)

postgres=# SHOW temp_tablespaces;
 temp_tablespaces 
------------------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT version()
postgres-# ;
                                                version                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.7.real (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Updating the information..
The disk usage result of the server..

```
➜  ~  df -h 
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  909G  465G  398G  54% /
udev                                                     10M   10M     0 100% /dev
tmpfs                                                   1.6G  616K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9ca82aa1-92c7-458c-a76d-9ce5c074f5dd  909G  465G  398G  54% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   4.8G   24M  4.8G   1% /run/shm
tmpfs                                                   4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /tmp
```

Adding the information `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main`.

```
total 56
drwx------ 8 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 28  2014 base
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 18 04:29 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 13 23:58 pg_clog
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 12  2014 pg_multixact
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 18 04:29 pg_notify
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 12  2014 pg_serial
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 19 18:24 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 19 05:34 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 12  2014 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 12  2014 pg_twophase
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    4 Aug 12  2014 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 19 17:34 pg_xlog
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  133 Aug 18 04:29 postmaster.opts
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   93 Aug 18 04:29 postmaster.pid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       36 Aug 12  2014 server.crt -> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       38 Aug 12  2014 server.key -> /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: Unfortunately that output did not include any of the clues I was hoping to find there. Could you include the output of `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_stat_tmp` and `df -h /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_stat_tmp` as well?

Comment: Post the output of `df -i`.

Answer (score 1):

You are out of storage where `pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp` resides. 
Which is exactly what the error message tells you.

Comment: not exactly, the system has a hell lot of memory. Its not full. thats why i am asking this question

Comment: If you think this is true, then update your question with the appropiate information.

Comment: I have the same problem, lots of space left, but postgres tells me otherwise.

Comment: it's actually an out of memory problem: its not the disk, but the ram

Answer (score 0):

As @Tobias said it's likely an out of RAM issue so edit your postgresql.conf to reduce shared_buffers or effective_cache_size... you can trigger [free](https://linux.die.net/man/1/free) at the time of the first "No space" log to see what the kernel thinks but really this is a PG bug. Restarting the service (temporarily) resolved the issue for me.